# Question about Meijer-G definition and identity

Tags: special-functions, solution-verification, contour-integration, products

I'm trying to wrap my mind around computation involving the Meijer $G$ function, as defined [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MeijerG-Function.html). (**Edit**: I'm actually using a somewhat mixed notation using the definitions from MathWorld and the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meijer_G-function#Definition_of_the_Meijer_G-function), but you get the idea.)
$$G^{m,n}_{p,q}\left(\begin{array}{c|c}\begin{matrix}a_1,\ldots,a_p\\b_1,\ldots,b_q\end{matrix}&z\end{array}\right)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_L \frac{\prod\limits_{j=1}^m \Gamma(b_j-s)\prod\limits_{j=1}^n\Gamma(1-a_j+s)}{\prod\limits_{j=n+1}^p \Gamma(a_j-s)\prod\limits_{j=m+1}^q\Gamma(1-b_j+s)}z^s\,ds$$
For the sake of practice, I'm interested in establishing identity $(5)$:
$$G^{1,2}_{2,2}\left(\begin{array}{c|c}\begin{matrix}1,1\\1,1\end{matrix}&z\end{array}\right)=\frac{z}{z+1}$$
From the definition, I'm getting
$$\begin{align*}G^{1,2}_{2,2}\left(\begin{array}{c|c}\begin{matrix}1,1\\1,1\end{matrix}&z\end{array}\right)&=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_L \frac{\prod\limits_{j=1}^1 \Gamma(b_j-s)\prod\limits_{j=1}^2\Gamma(1-a_j+s)}{\prod\limits_{j=3}^2 \Gamma(a_j-s)\prod\limits_{j=2}^2\Gamma(1-b_j+s)}z^s\,ds\\[2ex]
&=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_L \frac{\Gamma(1-s)\Gamma(s)}{\prod\limits_{j=3}^2 \Gamma(a_j-s)}z^s\,ds 
\end{align*}$$
and here's where I'm stuck. How would I approach the product in the denominator?

**Edit 2**: Since the lower index is larger than the upper index, do I just consider it an [empty product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product) and take the term in the denominator to be equal to $1$?

**Edit 3**: Now that I know how to proceed, here's my attempt at establishing the identity (though I don't use any hypergeometric functions; I'm trying my hand at the contour integral).
$$\begin{align*}G^{1,2}_{2,2}\left(\begin{array}{c|c}\begin{matrix}1,1\\1,1\end{matrix}&z\end{array}\right)
&=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_L\Gamma(1-s)\Gamma(s)z^s\,ds\\[2ex]
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\underset{s_0=k}{\text{Res}}\,\Gamma(1-s)\Gamma(s)z^s\\[2ex]
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\lim_{s\to k}(s-k)\Gamma(1-s)\Gamma(s)z^s\\[2ex]
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\lim_{s\to k}(s-k)\Gamma(1-s)\right)\Gamma(k)z^k\\[2ex]
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\lim_{s\to k}\frac{s-k}{1-s}\Gamma(2-s)\right)\Gamma(k)z^k\\[2ex]
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\lim_{s\to k}\frac{s-k}{(1-s)(2-s)}\Gamma(3-s)\right)\Gamma(k)z^k\\[2ex]
&\quad\vdots\\[2ex]
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\lim_{s\to k}\frac{s-k}{\prod\limits_{n=1}^k(n-s)}\right)\Gamma(k)z^k\\[2ex]
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\lim_{s\to k}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{\prod\limits_{n=1}^{k-1}(s-n)}\right)\Gamma(k)z^k\\[2ex]
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\lim_{s\to k}\frac{\Gamma(s-(k-1))}{\Gamma(s)}\right)(-z)^k\Gamma(k)\\[2ex]
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-z)^k\\[2ex]
&=-\frac{z}{1+z}
\end{align*}$$
(where $L$ is a contour that's surrounding the poles of $\Gamma(1-s)$, i.e. $s=k$ for integers $k\ge1$.) Unfortunately I seem to be off by a sign.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the *empty product* you're right. In case the lower index of a product is greater than the upper index, the product is equal to one (analogously to the empty sum which is zero in such cases).

> We can read e.g. in H. Bateman, *Higher Transcendental Function* Volume 1, section 5.3, p.207
>
> - Definition of $G$-Function: ... where an empty product is interpreted as $1$ ...

So, the expression reads as
\begin{align*}G^{1,2}_{2,2}\left(\begin{array}{c|c}\begin{matrix}1,1\\1,1\end{matrix}&z\end{array}\right)
&=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_L \Gamma(1-s)\Gamma(s)z^s\,ds 
\end{align*}

> If we use the representation based upon the *[hypergeometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function)*
>
> \begin{align*}
> G^{m,n}_{p,q}\left(\begin{array}{c|c}\begin{matrix}a_1,\ldots,a_p\\b_1,\ldots,b_q\end{matrix}&z\end{array}\right)&=
> \sum_{h=1}^m
> \frac{\displaystyle{\prod_{j=1}^{m}}\Gamma(b_j-b_h)^\ast\prod_{j=1}^{n}\Gamma(1+b_h-a_j)}{\displaystyle{\prod_{j=m+1}^{q}}\Gamma(1+b_h-b_j)\prod_{j=n+1}^{p}\Gamma(a_j-b_h)}z^{b_{h}}\\
> &\qquad\qquad\times
> {}_{p}F_{q-1}\left(\begin{array}{c|c}
> \begin{matrix}
> 1+b_h-\mathbb{a_p}\\
> (1+b_h-\mathbb{b_q})^\ast
> \end{matrix}&(-1)^{p-m-n}z\end{array}\right)
> \end{align*}
>   we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> G^{1,2}_{2,2}\left(\begin{array}{c|c}\begin{matrix}1,1\\1,1\end{matrix}&z\end{array}\right)&=
> \sum_{h=1}^1
> \frac{\displaystyle{\prod_{j=1}^{1}}\Gamma(b_j-b_1)^\ast\prod_{j=1}^{2}\Gamma(1+b_1-a_j)}{\displaystyle{\prod_{j=2}^{2}}\Gamma(1+b_1-b_j)\prod_{j=3}^{2}\Gamma(a_j-b_1)}z^{b_{1}}\\
> &\qquad\qquad\times
> {}_{2}F_{1}\left(\begin{array}{c|c}
> \begin{matrix}
> 1+b_1-\mathbb{a_2}\\
> (1+b_1-\mathbb{b_2})^\ast
> \end{matrix}&-z\end{array}\right)\\
> &=z\times{}_{2}F_{1}\left(\begin{array}{c|c}
> \begin{matrix}
> 1,1\\
> 1
> \end{matrix}&-z\end{array}\right)\\
> &=\frac{z}{1+z}
> \end{align*}

Comment: Thanks for the answer, now I'm looking into some info about the hypergeometric function. Quick note though: the denominator in the final result should be $1+z$, right?

Comment: @user170231: Typo corrected. Thanks for the hint and for accepting my answer. I suggest to start with *[$A = B$](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html)* by H.S. Wilf. It's fun to read and I'm pretty sure you will like it! :-)

Comment: @user170231: Thanks for granting the bounty!